# Exception on adding ContentPresenter to a ContentTemplate

Tags: c#, wpf, templates, xaml, wpf-controls

```
<ContentControl Content="Test">
    <ContentControl.ContentTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Border>
                <ContentPresenter />
            </Border>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ContentControl.ContentTemplate>
</ContentControl>
```

It throws stackoverflow exception. However if i use any other control else than ContentPresenter it works fine even ItemPresenter also works.I knows it doesnt make any sense to have ContentPresenter there but just for Knowledge want to know. Why it throws StackOverFlow exception and also Why does Intellisense shows it can be added(I mean it comes there in Intellisense that means syntatically its not wrong to have ContentPresenter there). Any help will be highly appericiated. Or is it any flaw in Wpf.

Comment: You can *not* count on *anything* intellisense tells you.

Comment: I reduced your question to the most general case.

Comment: Same problem here. Why do you say that "doesnt make any sense to have ContentPresenter there". It has a lot of sense when you don't want to recreate the whole representation, but just add something around. The solution ContentStringFormat="{}{0}" by the way works, but it's a bit let say, tricky. Shouldn't ContentPresenter handle gracefully this occurrence preventing the recursion by desing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The MSDN page for [ContentPresenter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.contentpresenter.aspx) says:

> When a ContentPresenter object is in a ControlTemplate of a
>   ContentControl, the Content, ContentTemplate, and
>   ContentTemplateSelector properties get their values from the
>   properties of the same names of the ContentControl. You can have the
>   ContentPresenter property get the values of these properties from
>   other properties of the templated parent by setting the ContentSource
>   property or binding to them.

I imagine it gives a StackOverflow because it just keeps on trying to apply the template to the ContentPresenter in the ContentTemplate, and then on the next one inside it, and then the one inside it, etc.

You also can do things like the following, so this pattern probably isn't always wrong, even though IntelliSense probably doesn't do any checking for these sorts of scenarios.

```
<ContentControl Content="Test"> 
    <ContentControl.ContentTemplate> 
        <DataTemplate> 
            <Border> 
                <ContentPresenter ContentStringFormat="{}{0}" />
            </Border> 
        </DataTemplate> 
    </ContentControl.ContentTemplate> 
</ContentControl>
```